# Having latex-like math formula in the legend

Tags: r, plot, latex, legend, plotmath

I know how to generate this in the legend:

> N_{1}(\alpha)

which can be done via

```
expression(N[1](alpha))
```

But I need something like this in latex:

> N_{1+}(\LargerCdot \alpha)

which I have no clue how to generate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few options:

1) Regular dot

```
expression(N[1+NULL](NULL %.% alpha))
```

2) Large dot: On the Mac, I used `option + 8` to get the large dot.

```
expression(paste(N[1+NULL],"(•", alpha,")"))
expression(paste(N[1+NULL],"(",~"•",NULL~alpha,")"))
```

Example using built-in `iris` data frame and `ggplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour=Species)) +
  scale_colour_discrete(labels=c(expression(N[1+NULL](NULL %.% alpha)), 
                                 expression(paste(N[1+NULL],"(•", alpha,")")),
                                 expression(paste(N[1+NULL],"(",~"•",NULL~alpha,")")))) +
  theme(legend.text=element_text(size=15))
```

[image]